# Log4j2:Dynamic creation of user based log files

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

**This is my scenario:** 
I want to log all the activities for users from the moment he login to Logout. each log needs to be stored in a file based on the user name appended with the date,log file will look like this "sam-2015-08-12.log".

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE xml>
    <Configuration status="WARN" name="PBMobile">
        <Appenders>

            <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
                <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level  %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
            </Console>

            <RollingFile name="error-log" append="true" fileName="D:/applog/error.log"
                filePattern="C:/applog/error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
                <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level  %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
                <Policies>
                    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"
                        modulate="true" />
                    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB" />
                </Policies>
            </RollingFile>

            <RollingFile name="trace-log" append="true" fileName="D:/applog/trace.log"
                filePattern="D:/applog/trace-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
                <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level  %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="512 MB" />
            </RollingFile>

            <Routing name="RoutingAppender">
                <Routes pattern="$${ctx:keyname}">
                    <Route>
                        <RollingFile name="Rolling-${ctx:keyname}"
                            fileName="D:/applog/${ctx:keyname}-${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
                            filePattern="D:/applog/${date:yyyy-MM}/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
                            <PatternLayout
                                pattern="%d{ABSOLUTE} %level{length=5} [%thread] %logger{1} - %msg%n" />
                            <Policies>
                                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="6"
                                    modulate="true" />
                                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
                            </Policies>

                        </RollingFile>
                    </Route>
                    <Route ref="Console" key="${ctx:keyname}" />
                </Routes>
            </Routing>
        </Appenders>
        <Loggers>
            <Root level="trace" additivity="false">
                <Appender-Ref ref="Console" level="trace" />
                <Appender-Ref ref="trace-log" level="trace" />
                <Appender-Ref ref="error-log" level="error" />
                <Appender-Ref ref="RoutingAppender" />
            </Root>
        </Loggers>
    </Configuration>
```

I used Threadcontext.put to pass the keyname during login method and removed in logout method

```
public string userlogin()
{
    {codes}.
    ThreadContext.put("keyname", User.getusername());
    {codes}.
    logger.trace("Login Success");
    return value;
}
```

**Issue :** 
The trace.log file is appended with the all traces, But the individual files for the user is not appended with log details of that particular user activity in user based log file (sam-2015-08-12.log).

only one line is appended individual log file (sam-2015-08-12.log)

```
19:15:24,112 TRACE [http-nio-9090-exec-5] Userlogin - Login Success
```

if a second user login the application at the same time, "mark-2015-08-12.log" files were created for second user,and then the log details of second user is appended in first user log file "sam-2015-08-12.log". those log also append for few activities only then no logs were appended in both file.

**guys help me out** ,is this configuration has any error ? i am new to this logging platform . I prepared logging configuration using the samples and examples from the internet.
Is there any other logging platform which suits for my requirement,please suggest me...

Comment: you may use the MDC approach https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html

Comment: could you pls suggest some samples , since newbie for this logging, bit hard to figure out .. is there any other logging platform which meets my requirement @AngeloImmediata

Comment: were you able to find the solution? If yes, would you mind posting that here?